# how to return datatable and integer in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am creating a method which returns `datatable`  and an `int` value.I have create a method which returns only `datatable`.Please  take a look on the code

```
    public static  DataTable ShutterstockSearchResults(string url)
    { 

       int TotalCont=0;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            //intigration using Basic Aouth with authrization headers

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            var username = "SC";
            var password = "SK";
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
            request.UserAgent = "MyApp 1.0";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                SearchResult myojb = (SearchResult)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(SearchResult));
               TotalCount = myojb.total_count;          

                dt.Columns.Add("Id");
                dt.Columns.Add("Discription");
                dt.Columns.Add("Small_Thumb_URl");
                dt.Columns.Add("Large_Thumb_URL");
                dt.Columns.Add("Prieview_URL");
                dt.Columns.Add("ContributorID");
                dt.Columns.Add("aspect");
                dt.Columns.Add("image_type");
                dt.Columns.Add("is_illustration");
                dt.Columns.Add("media_type");
                foreach (var item in myojb.data)
                {
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["ID"] = item.id;
                    row["Discription"] = item.description;
                    row["Small_Thumb_URl"] = item.assets.small_thumb.url;
                    row["Large_Thumb_URL"] = item.assets.large_thumb.url;
                    row["Prieview_URL"] = item.assets.preview.url;
                    row["ContributorID"] = item.contributor.id;
                    row["aspect"] = item.aspect;
                    row["image_type"] = item.image_type;
                    row["is_illustration"] = item.is_illustration;
                    row["media_type"] = item.media_type;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                // List<SearchResult> UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchResult>>(objText);
                // Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }          

        }

        catch (WebException ea)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ea.Message);
            using (var stream = ea.Response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }

        return dt;

    }
```

I want to return `datatable` and `TotalCont`.please help

Comment: I am not sure whether Totalcont is same as total number of rows of datatable.If yes then no need to return TotalCont. datatable.Rows.count will give you totalcount

Comment: @SagarShirke no Per page total is other and TotalCount is other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a method can only return one type.

You have two options:

1) Create a class that has a `DataTable` and an `int` field, such as:

```
public class MyReturnType
{
     public DataTable TheDataTable {get; set;}
     public int TotalCount {get; set;}
}
```

And return this type from your method.

2) You can add an `out` parameter to your method:

```
public static  DataTable ShutterstockSearchResults(string url, out totalCount)
```

And assign to `totalCount` within your method.

Comment: Sir return type like this `return dt,totalCount` ??

Comment: then how ?? can you please explain ??

Comment: @Gitz second option provided by Klaus Byskov pedersen is better for your condition..you can refer following simple article for learning how to use out parameter...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static Tuple<DataTable, int> ShutterstockSearchResults(string url)
    {
        [...]
        return new Tuple<DataTable, int>(dt, totalCount);
    }

    public static void SomeConsumerMethod()
    {
        var result = ShutterstockSearchResults(myPath);
        DataTable dt = result.Item1;
        int totalCount = result.Item2;
    }
```

Comment: You could also do `return Tuple.Create(dt, totalCount);`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the comments in Klaus answer:

```
    public class MyReturnType
    {
         public DataTable TheDataTable {get; set;}
         public int TotalCount {get; set;}
    }
```

and in your method:

```
public static  MyReturnType ShutterstockSearchResults(string url)
    { 
       MyReturnType result=new MyReturnType();
       int TotalCont=0;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            //intigration using Basic Aouth with authrization headers

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            var username = "SC";
            var password = "SK";
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
            request.UserAgent = "MyApp 1.0";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                SearchResult myojb = (SearchResult)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(SearchResult));
               TotalCount = myojb.total_count;          

                dt.Columns.Add("Id");
                dt.Columns.Add("Discription");
                dt.Columns.Add("Small_Thumb_URl");
                dt.Columns.Add("Large_Thumb_URL");
                dt.Columns.Add("Prieview_URL");
                dt.Columns.Add("ContributorID");
                dt.Columns.Add("aspect");
                dt.Columns.Add("image_type");
                dt.Columns.Add("is_illustration");
                dt.Columns.Add("media_type");
                foreach (var item in myojb.data)
                {
                    var row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["ID"] = item.id;
                    row["Discription"] = item.description;
                    row["Small_Thumb_URl"] = item.assets.small_thumb.url;
                    row["Large_Thumb_URL"] = item.assets.large_thumb.url;
                    row["Prieview_URL"] = item.assets.preview.url;
                    row["ContributorID"] = item.contributor.id;
                    row["aspect"] = item.aspect;
                    row["image_type"] = item.image_type;
                    row["is_illustration"] = item.is_illustration;
                    row["media_type"] = item.media_type;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                // List<SearchResult> UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchResult>>(objText);
                // Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }          

        }

        catch (WebException ea)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ea.Message);
            using (var stream = ea.Response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }

        result.TheDataTable=dt;
        result.TotalCount=TotalCount;
        return result:

    }
```

Comment: and how to call it on my cs page ??

Comment: the same way you call it before, when the return type was DataTable

Comment: On my code I call it something like ` DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ShutterstockAPI.ShutterstockSearchResults(URL)` but its not working @apomene

Comment: now it should be:DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt = ShutterstockAPI.ShutterstockSearchResults(URL).TheDataTable;

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs an additional `out` parameter if you want to "return" more than one value. Just pass an uninitialized variable of the desired type into your method and assign that variable inside.

```
public void Test()
{
    int i;
    DataTable ShutterstockSearchResults("Some string", out i);
}
```

your `ShutterstockSearchResults` method needs to be modified accordingly:

```
public static DataTable ShutterstockSearchResults(string url, out int outParam)
{
    outParam = 10;

    // do other stuff
}
```

If you do not change `outParam` any further inside `ShutterstockSearchResults`, it will have the value 10 after returning to `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a Tuple.  Consider the following simple example:

```
public class EmptyClass
{
    public static void Main(){
        EmptyClass something = new EmptyClass ();

        Tuple<String, int> tuple = something.returnMe ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Item 1: " + tuple.Item1);
        Console.WriteLine ("Item 2: " + tuple.Item2);
    }

    public EmptyClass ()
    {
    }

    public Tuple<String, int> returnMe() {
        return Tuple.Create ("Hello", 2);
    }
}
```